# I cannot convert a Firebase Timestamp to ISO format because I get this error: TypeError: thread.createdAt.toDate is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, datetime, google-cloud-functions

Inside a Firebase Cloud Function I have a `thread` object that has a property named `createdAt`. The value of that property is a Firebase Timestamp.

The `thread` object looks like this:

```TypeScript
{
  "id": "h7PBcWd1aZ8KPQT36nRv",
  "message": "",
  "authorId": "q2fY5Nk4mqP1nSHN1qPFKD7NCfV2",
  "content": "eeeee",
  "ticketId": "FvqhdvSvLGlG7I3Nn9v7",
  "uploadToSupport": true,
  "createdAt": {
    "_nanoseconds": 938000000,
    "_seconds": 1662693778
}
```

Now I want to convert the `createdAt` Firebase Timestamp into ISO Format so I can use it with an external 3rd party API. For example: `2018-09-10T11:54:03.000Z`.

I am trying to convert it using the Firebase [toDate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate) method, like this:

```TypeScript
const createdTime = thread.createdAt.toDate().toISOString();
```

But when I run the Cloud Function it throws an error saying:

> TypeError: thread.createdAt.toDate is not a function

Comment: How did you create the createdAt field?  That detail is extremely important. It looks like an object that is not really a Firestore timestamp, but contains some fields the are use by a timestamp.  If it's just an object, you can't simply call toDate on it - plain JavaSctipt objects don't have that method.

Comment: In POJS you'd want something like `new Date(obj.createdAt._seconds*1e3 + obj.createdAt._nanoseconds/1e6).toISOString()`, i.e. convert the seconds and nanoseconds to a single millisecond value and pass that to the *Date* constructor. Using that method, the value in the OP converts to "2022-09-09T03:22:58.938Z".

Comment: @DougStevenson you were right. I was using `threadDocSnapshot.data()` to get the doc, and then passed it into the problematic function as a plain object. Now I am passing in just `threadDocSnapshot` and using `threadDocSnapshot.data()?.createdAt.toDate().toISOString()` which works fine. Do you want to turn your comment into an answer or shall I?

Comment: @RobG thanks for this code snippet! It looks great but as described in the comment above I'm going for a different solution this time. Will save it for other use cases in the future. Maybe this would also be good to add as an answer so others can easily find it?

Answer (score 1):

`Date()` uses milliseconds to convert to a date string. You must convert seconds and nanoseconds to milliseconds and sum them, *then* convert to a date

```js
let docData = {
  "createdAt": {
    "_nanoseconds": 938000000,
    "_seconds": 1662693778
  }
}

//since Date() uses milliseconds, convert nanoseconds and seconds to millis, then use toLocaleString()
let dateString = new Date(docData.createdAt._seconds * 1000 + docData.createdAt._nanoseconds/1000000).toLocaleString(); 

console.log(dateString);
```